# How to read data from Excel starting from given row and getting proper type inference

Tags: .net, excel, datatable, ado, type-inference

I am importing data from .xls and .xlsx files using these connection strings

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\file.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;MaxScanRows=16;Empty Text Mode=NullAsEmpty;"
```

or

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\file.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;MaxScanRows=16;Empty Text Mode=NullAsEmpty;"
```

I load data in a datatable.

```
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connString)
        connection.Open()
        wsName = "myWorksheet$"

        Dim SQL As [String] = String.Format("SELECT {1} FROM [{0}]", wsName, "*")

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, connection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)

        dtb = ds.Tables(0)

    End Using
```

and I get properly typed fields if data starts in the first rows of the excel file. Unluckily some of the excel files (both xls and xlsx formats) can have several rows of headers and other annoyance before actual data. This can disrupt the sampling of Jet ending in fields typed as text when they should be numbers.

It seems that it is not possibile to force jet to start reading from line X.

I also tried to use a DataReader to advance to the beginning of data then create the DataTable

```
        dtb.Load(reader)
```

but the problem is the same, field type is based on the first actual rows.

So I ask for advice about how to get a DataTable with fields typed accordingly with data starting from row x of an Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dark road you have started down. I've been down it recently and after trying several options, I ended up going with [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader). This is a nice .NET library that does a decent job importing data from .xls and .xlsx files. Basic importing is below:

```
IExcelDataReader excelReader = default(IExcelDataReader);
using (System.IO.FileStream excelStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower() == ".xls") {
        excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(excelStream);
    } else {
        excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(excelStream);
    }
    excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
}

// Library doesn't throw proper exceptions, create our own
if (excelReader.ExceptionMessage != string.Empty) {
    throw new ExcelReaderException(excelReader.ExceptionMessage, fileName);
}

DataSet excelPages = excelReader.AsDataSet();
```

I was working with legacy code, so I still had to convert the import to a DataSet. However, you can work with Sheet, Page and Cell objects if you have the opportunity to. The one issue I have hit so far that I haven't found a *nice* workaround for is sometimes the library will import blank rows from a spreadsheet (a few times, thousands of them). Our current work-around is to prune those after import.

For OLEDB: I believe there is a registry update you can do that sets the read ahead row count used by OLEDB to determine the data type the column should be set to. This is a terrible option, as it has to be done on each client machine. Also, there are other issues you will most likely hit with OLEDB based Excel imports. I can't remember them all, but it was enough for us to abandon it entirely.